# what can i do against error Assets\Modells\Player Controls\enemyAi.cs(20,20): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'UnityEngine.Ray'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

this is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class enemyAi
{
    public Transform player;
    public Transform Monster;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

   // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Ray lRay = Physics.Raycast(Monster.position, Monster.forward - Monster.right);
        Ray fRay = Physics.Raycast(Monster.position, Monster.forward);
        Ray rRay = Physics.Raycast(Monster.position, Monster.forward + Monster.right);
    }
}
```

i don't have any idea how to fix it and i've spend 20 minutes fixing another error that i had before that lead to this

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html
from the left side Ray = from the right side bool

Comment: A Raycast tells you if you have actually hit something. That is, it returns a boolean. It does not return a Ray. The Ray (or simply an origin and direction as you're using here) are inputs.

Answer (score 0):

What Bart says on comments is true, but you can actually store the data in a [RaycastHit](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html) and then process it like a bool.

I consider it a good practice since you can take way more from a ray this way.

Comment: This answer might be improved by showing which overload of the method could be used to achieve what the OP seems to want.

Comment: Just do `RaycastHit r = Physics.Raycast(whatever);` And `r` will return a bool.